# How to keep the Master Boot Record when installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uninstall, mbr

Recently I tried out Ubuntu in a virtual machine, and I really liked it. I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, but because Grub overwrites the Master Boot Record, I'm scared that I might not be able to restore it if I want to remove Ubuntu for some reason. I read about it online, and found that I can create a seperate boot partition in the installer. Does that mean it keeps the original Master Boot Record, and if i uninstall Ubuntu it will automaticly switch back to it, or still overwrites it? (Sorry for my bad english, I'm not a native english speaker.)

Comment: There is no single answer that works for everyone. IMO you should use only one boot or efi partition (multiple efi partitions make it more complex). From there it really depends on your bios. Some bios allow you to select which OS to boot (my laptop). Other bios are does not matter. On my desktop I had the problem that I could not initially dual boot, either Linux or Windows. I solved by configuring the windows boot loader from windows - bcdedit https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/104999/fedora-linux-not-found-in-the-boot-startup/

Comment: I suggest you go with the default during the installer , the defaults work fine for the vast majority of users. If for some reason you have a problem, run boot-repair from a live usb - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair . Unless you aer knowledgable of how BOTH Windows and Ubuntu boot, dont go changing the defaults

Comment: See the linked question for how to restore Microsoft’s bootloader. I hope that addresses your question and fear of not being able to restore Windows if you decide to leave Ubuntu behind.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the partition table on your hard disk where resides windows 10, i think you should take in consideration an installation of ubuntu in a usb stick with grub installed there (in the usb stick) and booting from that. 
In that way your hard disk with windows 10 will remain untouched. Is not an elegant solution but is clean and painless. 
In the meantime you will learn a lot of things of Linux using both operative systems and then with more confidence and practice in Linux you will decide what to do.
(My english is a litle rusty, pardon me).

Cheers.